Graphite backend Timeout
graphite metrics are not being loaded after upgrading the OS from CentOS to Alma Linux. Seeing below error in the /data/graphite/storage/log/webapp/exception.log
File "/data/graphite/webapp/graphite/storage.py", line 121, in wait_jobs     raise Exception(message) Exception: Timed out after 3.001059s for find <FindQuery: * from * until *>
I tried few ways to see how the database(whisper) can be started but all can I see on the Internet is starting the 'carbon-cache' service which is already up and running.
Tried to see what is happening with the code pointed by the error message. Purely it is a timeout issue. But not sure why it is timing out
/data/graphite/webapp/graphite/storage.py
def wait_jobs(self, jobs, timeout, context):
  if not jobs: return []

  start = time.time()
  results = []
  failed = []
  done = 0
  try:
    for job in self.pool_exec(jobs, timeout):
        elapsed = time.time() - start
        done += 1
        if job.exception:
            failed.append(job)
            log.info("Exception during %s after %fs: %s" % (
                job, elapsed, str(job.exception))
            )
        else:
            log.debug("Got a result for %s after %fs" % (job, elapsed))
            results.append(job.result)
  except PoolTimeoutError:
    message = "Timed out after %fs for %s" % (
        time.time() - start, context
    )
    log.info(message)
    if done == 0:
        raise Exception(message)

